# Проблемы с повторным подключением к Xdebug через NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

Появилась проблема с повторным подключением к Xdebug через NetBeans, попытки разобраться самому результата не принесли.

При первом подключении всё работает. Если закрыть подключение и заново открыть, то шанс появления проблемы составляет около 60-70%. После очередного закрытия с последующим открытием подключения шанс появления проблемы становится выше 90% (лишь 1 раз на третьем подключении проблемы не было, во всех остальных случаях максимум 2 раза подключаться мог). Перезапуск NetBeans позволяет снова подключится в Xdebug.

Использую Xdebug и NetBeans последней версии, браузер Opera 30.0.